# How do I Code one entity into another?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, entity

This is what my SQL tables look like:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Families` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mother_id` INT DEFAULT NULL ,
  `father_id` INT DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`Parents` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And this is what my family entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Families")
public class Family implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id") 
    private String id;

    @Column(name="mother_id")
    private int mother;

    @Column(name="father_id")
    private int father;
}
```

Which is great and all, but I would really LOVE if I could do something like this (note I also have a Parent entity already defined):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Families")
public class Family implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id") 
    private String id;

    @OneToOne
    @Column(name="mother_id")
    private Parent mother;

    @OneToOne
    @Column(name="father_id")
    private Parent father;
}
```

How could I go about making this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Hibernate does everything for you.

- You don't need to annotate columns with `@Column` which already have `@OneToOne` or other association annotations
- If you want to use other than default foreign key(by default name consists of `field` + `_id`), you should use `@JoinColumn` annotation

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Families")
public class Family implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id") 
    private String id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mother_idd") 
    private Parent mother;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "father_idd")
    private Parent father;
}
```